# change font type and size of headings in R markdown with PDF output

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I've searched and searched (even the pandoc manual with its gazillion pages) but can't find the answer:

how can I change font type and size of headings in R markdown with PDF output? For instance, let's say I want all level 1 headings to be 12 pt bold Times New Roman numbered "1."; all level 2 headings to be 12 pt italics Times New Roman numbered "1.1"

thanks

Comment: I think this is a LaTeX question, not a markdown one. You might be able to use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37881/82137 and adapt it into a YAML header (perhaps with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211638/82137). It seems a little kludgy, admittedly, but I don't think pandoc enables it specifically (esp since it would be latex-only, no direct application to other output formats like md, docx, and odt).

Comment: Yes, this is all about figuring out how to set the style of section titles in LaTeX, so tex.stackexchange.com should have some useful answers. pandoc does specifically allow for customisation in the header, when you specify that info in the YAML for your RMarkdown file it's just passed through to the appropriate pandoc argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can put LaTeX in `header-includes:` or directly set some of the [Variables for LaTeX](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex):

```
---
fontsize: 12pt
fontfamily: Latin Modern
---

# my content
```